# Adicionar argumento na linha de comando protocolo callto

Tags: argumento, sip

Eu trabalho fazendo ligações usando o programa MicroSip. Porem eu to com dificuldades pra automatizar as discagens em apenas um click. Eu achei uma extensão na Chrome Store que permite isso convertendo os números no navegador em links callto:, tel: ou sip:. Só que o mesmo manda os números para o programa sem o 0 na frente o que causa erro de discagem e infelizmente eu sou obrigado a trabalhar com esse programa (mudar não é uma opção). Queria saber se tem como acrescentar um argumento na linha de comando no registro de um desses protocolos para adicionar o 0 na frente dos números ou alguma outra gambiarra que adicione essa porcaria de 0.

Agradeço desde já.